# Erro no cálculo de valores de um vetor

Tags: c, struct, array

Estou parado nessa parte do meu trabalho no case 2 da faculdade, a saida fica toda embaralhada, por exemplo:

> O lucro sera de `-1,#$%#!@`

```
#define vetor 40

struct Produto{
    char codigo[10];
    char descricao[100];
    float precoCompra;
    float precoVenda;
    int quantEstoque;
};

int main(){

    // Declaração das variaveis
    struct Produto estoque[vetor];

    float lucro;
    float lucro2;

    int opcao;
    int opcao2;
    int count;
    int i;

   // Inicios do menu do programa
   system("cls");  // Limpa a tela

    puts( "Escolha uma opção:" );
    puts( "1 - Cadastrar produto." );
    puts( "2 - Lucro da venda de todos os produtos." );
    scanf( "%d", &opcao );  // Lê a entrada do usuário

    fflush(stdin);  // Limpa o lixo da memoria
    system("cls");  // Limpa a tela

    // Inicios do switch case
    switch( opcao ){

        case 1:

            count = 1;

            system("cls");

            printf( "Deseja cadastrar um produto?\n1 - SIM\n2 - NAO\n" );
            scanf( "%d", &opcao2 );

            system("cls");

            while( opcao2 != 2 ){

                fflush(stdin);

                printf( "Entre com o codigo do produto: " );
                scanf( "%s", &estoque[count].codigo );

                printf( "Entre com a descricao do produto: " );
                scanf( "%s", &estoque[count].descricao );

               printf( "Entre com o preco da compra: " );
               scanf( "%f", &estoque[count].precoCompra );

                printf( "Entre com o preco da venda: " );
                scanf( "%f", &estoque[count].precoVenda );

                printf( "Entre com a quantidade em estoque:" );
                scanf( "%d", &estoque[count].quantEstoque );

                count++;

                system("cls");

                printf( "Deseja cadastrar outro produto?\n1 - SIM\n2 - NAO\n" );
                scanf( "%d", &opcao2 );

            }
            return main();

        case 2:

            lucro = 0;

            printf( "Lucro total com a venda de cada produto.\n" );

            for( i = 1; i <= vetor; i++ ){

                    fflush(stdin);

                    lucro = lucro + ( estoque[i].precoVenda * estoque[i].quantEstoque      );
                }

            fflush(stdin);

            printf( "O lucro sera de: %.2f", lucro );

            getch();
            return main();

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema 1**

Você esta calculando valores com lixo de memória.

Em C, todos os vetores são indexados partindo da posição `0` até a `N-1`, sendo `N` a quantidade de elementos do vetor.

No seu caso, o vetor `estoque` possui `vetor` posições. No seu looping, você esta inicializando `i` com `1` e caminhando até `i <= vetor`. Logo, quando `i == vetor`, você fará referência a posições de memória não inicializadas, podendo causar desde resultados aleatórios (aka `undefined behavior`) até falhas de segmentação (`access vilation` se você usa Windows, `segmentation fault` se usa praticamente qualquer outra coisa hehehe).

*Solução*

Altere para o seu looping ir de `i = 0` enquanto `i < vetor`.

No `case 1` também será necessário corrigir, uma vez que a você utiliza a variável `count` para acessar os elementos do `estoque` e esta esta sendo inicializada com o valor `1`.

**Problema 2**

Caso você não possua todos os elementos do vetor inicializados (por exemplo se a constante (estou inferindo já que você não postou a declaração) `vetor` valer `5` mas inserir apenas 3 itens na variável `estoque`), você também irá ler lixo de memória no looping do `case 2`.

*Solução*

Mantenha uma variável de controle (pode ser a própria variável `count`, porém em escopo global) com a quantidade de elementos no vetor `estoque`, e ao invés de percorrer o vetor `estoque` inteiro no `case 2`, percorra apenas os `count` primeiro elementos. Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    // faça o cálculo aqui.
}
```

Há alguns outros problemas no código, mas a princípio, são estes os problemas que estão causando os erros encontrados.

Além disso, estou assumindo primeiro semestre do curso de computação, logo não vou ser chato e criticar todos os problemas de uma única vez...

Espero ter ajudado,
Boa sorte!